# How do I uninstall git version 1.6.5.1 from Mac OS X 10.5.8

Tags: git, macos

How do I uninstall git version 1.6.5.1 from Mac OS X 10.5.8?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

if `which git` returns /usr/local/git/bin/git as jimmy pointed out,

```
rm -rf /usr/local/git
rm /etc/paths.d/git
rm /etc/manpaths.d/git
```

should do the trick

source [here](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/wiki/Uninstall)

Comment: +1 Same answer as here:  http://serverfault.com/questions/166492/how-to-remove-git-mac-os-x

Answer (score 8):

I recently had to upgrade from 1.9.3 to 2.2.1 on Mac OSX 10.10.1

I successfully ran the installer for 2.2.1, but the command line "git --version" still showed 1.9.3.

It turns out that  2.2.1 was successfully installed to /usr/local/git/bin and the directory was added to my path. However, 1.9.3 was installed in /usr/bin, which appeared in my shell PATH variable before /usr/local/git/bin, and so was being called before the updated version.

This was fixed by running "sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/git*" and restarting the command line.

FYI: if you think you're having a similar issue, you can find the various versions of git in your PATH by running "type -a git"

Answer (score 7):

You can do `which git` to get the path to the git binary. It should be pretty clear where the git stuff is installed from that. I believe the graphical installer puts it in `/usr/local/git` by default. Just remove that directory, and if you want, remove it from your `PATH` environment variable as well.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is specifically about git 1.x, but if you're on git 2.x, there is an uninstall script in your git directory. In my case, it was at:

`/usr/local/git/uninstall.sh`

Comment: MacOS 10.12.5 seem to not have this file.

Answer (score 2):

Just download the new git version you want, and run uninstall.sh (that comes in the git.zip)