# Remove Git from my mac?

Tags: macos, git

I want to remove Git completely from my Mac machine.

How can I do it?

Comment: Why remove it? Is it causing a problem? Also, this is more appropriate for superuser.com or apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I uninstall git version 1.6.5.1 from Mac OS X 10.5.8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612326/how-do-i-uninstall-git-version-1-6-5-1-from-mac-os-x-10-5-8)

Comment: I installed it through the commands specified at github site

Comment: If you install with sudo, uninstalling git can be a more expedient course of action relative to manually correcting all the associated permissions

Comment: this works for me              sudo rm -rf /usr/local/git /usr/bin/git /etc/paths.d/git /etc/manpaths.d/git