# test to check if manual git install is removed on Mac OS High Sierra

Tags: git

I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612326/how-do-i-uninstall-git-version-1-6-5-1-from-mac-os-x-10-5-8)

```
rm -rf /usr/local/git
rm /etc/paths.d/git
rm /etc/manpaths.d/git
```

I want to be 100% sure I did it right before reinstalling using homebrew

so when I type `git --version`

I get the message:

> Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please
>   run “sudo xcodebuild -license” and then retry this command.

and after typing `which git`

the result is still

> /usr/bin/git

I'm not sure if it's gone yet -what else needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install the `Homebrew` version then simply do:

```
brew install git
```

`Homebrew` should handle the package dependencies, update the `$PATH` environment variable, and include any symbolic links necessary to utilize the newly installed brew version. Packages are installed in the `/usr/local/Cellar` directory and typically puts executables or symbolic links in `/usr/local/bin`.

The `which git` command is most likely showing you the Apple installed version of `Git` (located in `/usr/bin`), which you probably should leave be. Removing the default version could lead to nasty surprises down the road. `Homebrew` should typically not interfere with system installed packages.

You can check your version of `Git` by doing:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.15.2 (Apple Git-101.1) # this is the system installed version
```

If you installed `Git` at some point from the Git package (non-Apple version) `.pkg` then you can always use the package uninstaller that it comes with or execute it's script manually:

**uninstall.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash -e

if [ ! -r "/usr/local/git" ]; then
  echo "Git doesn't appear to be installed via this installer.  Aborting"
  exit 1
fi
echo "This will uninstall git by removing /usr/local/git/, and symlinks"
printf "Type 'yes' if you are sure you wish to continue: "
read response
if [ "$response" == "yes" ]; then
  # remove all of the symlinks we've created
  pkgutil --files com.git.pkg | grep bin | while read f; do
    if [ -L /usr/local/$f ]; then
      sudo rm /usr/local/$f
    fi
  done

  # forget receipts.
  pkgutil --packages | grep com.git.pkg | xargs -I {} sudo pkgutil --forget {}
  echo "Uninstalled"

  # The guts all go here.
  sudo rm -rf /usr/local/git/
else
  echo "Aborted"
  exit 1
fi

exit 0
```